# Null Pointer Exception while using onProgressChanged inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock side navigation fragments in my android application. However, i am using 6 fragments all containing a webviews with progress bar.

Here's one of the fragments:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    private WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        mWebview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        mWebview.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
             public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
             {
                   //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
                   getActivity().setTitle("Loading...");
                   getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

                   // Return the app name after finish loading
                   if(progress == 100)
                   getActivity().setTitle(R.string.Fragment1);
                 }

             });


        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                //Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.LINK");
        WebSettings zoomenable = mWebview.getSettings();
        zoomenable.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        WebSettings wideviewenable  = mWebview.getSettings();
        wideviewenable.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        mWebview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
              startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        mWebview.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
             if(mWebview.canGoBack())
             {
             mWebview.goBack();
             return true;
             }

             return false;
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                mWebview.reload();
                return true;
            default:return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

The problem i am facing that when selecting one of the links located in the side navigation and the progress bar is not yet finished, it gives me null pointer exception in onProgressChanged method.

in the main activity i used these two line of codes to enable progress bar:

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
this.getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

Here's the log cat error:

```
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at petra.app.Fragment1$1.onProgressChanged(Fragment1.java:45)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:533)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-23 18:54:20.687: E/AndroidRuntime(20112):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace from logcat

Comment: @matiash, i posted the logcat errors, please check them.

Comment: have you checked if the getActivity is returning null?

Comment: How to check so?, and i don't think so cause in the first fragment it loads the progress and page correctly, but when navigating between fragments rapidly it'll give this exception.

Comment: you can try Activity activity = getActivity(); if (activity != null) then you can use it for changing the title and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

> ```
>     mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
>          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
>          {
>                //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
>                Activity activity = getActivity();
>                if (activity != null) {
>                   activity.setTitle("Loading...");
>                   activity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded
>                   // Return the app name after finish loading
>                   if(progress == 100)
>                   activity.setTitle(R.string.Fragment1);
>                 }
>              }
>          });
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm almost sure that this is caused when the porgress published by the WebChromeClient is fired when the activity is no longer visible.

You should check if the "getActivity()" call return null, and ...

To apply corrections on your code, look at this:

```
mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
         {
              // here you check the value of getActivity() and break up if needed
             if(getActivity() == null)
                 return;

               //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
               getActivity().setTitle("Loading...");
               getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

               // Return the app name after finish loading
               if(progress == 100)
               getActivity().setTitle(R.string.Fragment1);
             }

         });
```

Comment: The question refers to the progress indicator that is already in the activity, not using a dialog.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. I edited my response above.

Comment: getActivity() is not defined within the scope of onProgressChanged() method.